# Phaser how to have an object accessible in multiple scenes

Tags: phaser-framework, scene

I've made an inventory object for my game. Here is its code:

```
class player extends Phaser.GameObjects{

constructor(){
    super();
    this.stuff = [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];
}

collcet(item) {
    this.space = 0;
    while (this.space < 10){
        if (this.items[this.space] == null){
            this.items[this.space] == item;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
}

has(item){
    this.space = 0;
    this.result = false
    while (this.space < 10){
        if (this.items[this.space] == item){
            this.result = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
    return this.result;
}

takeOut(item){
    this.space = 0;
    while (this.space < 10){
        if (this.items[this.space] == item){
            this.items[this.space] == null;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
}

}
```

I want to have a single inventory that is accessible in all scenes of my game, but I'm using switch statements to change scenes, which I faintly remember don't allow for data to be shared between scenes. Is there any way I can have this inventory work, or do I need to rethink the whole thing?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode, employing arcade physics.

Answer (score 1):

Start or `add` your scenes first, then switch between them. When you start them, pass your game state:

```
export default class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: "BootScene" });
    }
    preload() {
        this.gameState = {
            inventory: [ some stuff ],
        }
    }
    create() {
        const startScene = false;
        this.scene.add("InventoryScene", InventoryScene, startScene, this.gameState);
        this.scene.start("GameScene", this.gameState);
    }
}
```

Now switch between your scenes:

```
export default class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: "GameScene" });
    }
    init(gameState) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
    }
    update() {
        if player presses "i" {
            this.scene.switch("InventoryScene");
        }
    }
```

The state you passed is available within the scene.

```
export default class InventoryScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: "InventoryScene" });
    }
    init(gameState) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
    }
    update() {
        const { some stuff } = this.gameState.inventory;
        if player presses "esc" {
            this.scene.switch("GameScene");
        }
    }
```