# Having trouble using an array that is accessible in multiple scenes

Tags: arrays, phaser-framework, scene

I have recently added the commented lines of code to my game's main.js file.

```
let config = {
type: Phaser.Canvas,
physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
        debug: true,
        gravity: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    }
},
width: 1600,
height: 900,
scene: [ LivingRoom, DiningRoom, StairRoom ],
//inventory: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
};

let keyA, keyD, keyW, keyT, keyG;

let borderUISize = config.height / 15;
let borderPadding = borderUISize / 3;

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
//game.config.inventory = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
```

Doing so makes an array that is accessible in all of the scenes connected to this main.js. I plan to use this array as an inventory system for storing various items in my game. Thus, I made the following methods within the scenes in order to use the array. The lines that use the array contain this.game.config.inventory[this.space].

```
collect(item) {
    this.space = 0;
    while (this.space < 10){
        if (this.game.config.inventory[this.space] == null){
            this.game.config.inventory[this.space] == item;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
}

has(item){
    this.space = 0;
    this.result = false
    while (this.space < 10){
        if (this.game.config.inventory[this.space] == item){
            this.result = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
    return this.result;
}

takeOut(item){
    this.space = 0;
    while (this.space < 10){
        if (this.game.config.inventory[this.space] == item){
            this.game.config.inventory[this.space] == null;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the collect method doesn't seem to be working, as when I used it to put a test item in the inventory and then used the has method to see if it was there, it still came up false. I can't tell what I did wrong, but I hope someone else can. Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode, employing arcade physics.

Comment: Is this not the same question? [Phaser how to have an object accessible in multiple scenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73561495/phaser-how-to-have-an-object-accessible-in-multiple-scenes)

Comment: Not exaclty. Sometime after I submitted that question with no answer, I found this: 

https://www.stephengarside.co.uk/blog/phaser-3-custom-config-global-variables/

It was through this article, I found out how to create variables that can be accessed across scenes, and thus did so with an array. Now I'm just having some trouble using it.

Comment: Hey, just did some testing, and found that this isn't going to work. Turns out that variables created through this process can't be changed. So, back to the drawing board.

Comment: btw.: what might help getting answers, is when you ask a question and than get an answer is, to upvote and/or accept it, if it helped. Or if you found yourself a solution to share it. and being patient. reposting the same question wont help.

Comment: Hey, I don't know I you're still looking at this, but I'll ask anyway. I while looking for a way to make this inventory work, I came upon the game registry. Here is the website I found, with the info I found useful under the title "Exchange data via the game registry":

https://phaser.io/phaser3/devlog/119

I was thinking of using booleans through this technique to show if an item is in the inventory or not, but I have 2 issues that I'm not sure how to solve.

Comment: The first, while the website shows how to set values within the registry, it doesn't clearly show how to call values from the registry. I was thinking of having a method that checks if a certain boolean that's in the registry is true or not, but without a way to call certain values from the registry, it's not going to work.

The next issue, I noticed that the website only shows values being set in one scene and never shows if they can be changed by the same method in other scenes. I need to know if doing so is possible, or else this entire idea is a bust. If you know, please tell.